# which one goes to zero faster

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let be a squence: $x_n=\{1,1/2,1/4,1/8,...\}$, then based on that we have two other sequences:

$$y_n=\{x_n^a\}$$
and
$$z_n=\{x_n^b\}|ln(\{x_n\})|^c$$.

It should be noted that $a>b$ but there is no correlation between others.
It is necessary for me to know which one goes faster to zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x_n = 2^{-n}$, we have $y_n = x_n^a = (2^{-n})^a = 2^{-an}$ and

$z_n = x_n^b|\ln x_n|^c = (2^{-n})^b|\ln 2^{-n}|^c = 2^{-nb}|-n\ln 2|^c = (\ln 2)^c \cdot n^c \cdot 2^{-nb}$.

Hence, $\dfrac{z_n}{y_n} = \dfrac{(\ln 2)^c \cdot n^c \cdot 2^{-nb}}{2^{-na}} = (\ln 2)^c \cdot n^c \cdot 2^{(a-b)n}$.

Can you tell whether this goes to $0$ or $\infty$?

**Hint**: If $c \ge 0$, then this is easy. If $c < 0$, then L'Hopital's Rule will be helpful.